# Summation with arithmetic series

Tags: summation

I have doubts how to solve summation if on the top there is something else than $n$ more specificially:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}
i=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$

Is my solution correct? I just replace $n+1$ to $n$ in the formula for the special case of arithmetic series.

Comment: Yes, the formula is valid for all $n$, in particular for $n+1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $k=n+1$ then the sum becomes:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}
i=\frac{k(k+1)}{2},$$ you can prove it using the induction.
Now substitute $k$ with $n+1$ and you obtain the result.